# Nginx: how 'brotli' directive use in 'if' context

Tags: nginx

in ngx_brotli it point out `brotli` directive can use in `if` context.
https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3voy.png)

```
    set $t 1;
    if ($t) {
        brotli on;
    }
    brotli_comp_level 3;
    brotli_buffers 16 8k;
    brotli_min_length 1;
    brotli_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;
```

it tips me `nginx: [emerg] "brotli" directive is not allowed here in` when I startup nginx

Comment: Is this inside a `location` block? Generally `if` and `if-in-location` are separate contexts.

Comment: in `server` block